# Why am I getting "HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found" for the following code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

mum = sns.load_dataset("EE770_Mumbai")
sns.relplot(x="Hour of the year", y="RH(%)", data=mum)
```

Answer (score 1):

`seaborn.load_dataset` is documented here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html

In summary, it loads a sample dataset from here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data.

The dataset "EE770_Mumbai" doesn't exist at that Github address.

You can run `seaborn.get_dataset_names()` to show the datasets currently available